# JQuery - Help on .remove() function

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with my code, I just add some remove() function, and I see only one problem with this with the site section and the PRM section.

Here is a video capture of the "problem" : http://recordit.co/HGak32nwpy

When I append items, I don't really want to erase the last one appended but the last of my section. For exemple if I append 2 sites on the first company and 3 other one on the second company. If I press the remove() button on the first company, I want only to append the last site FROM the first company and not the last one created. Same thing for the PRM section.

Thanks in advance for your help !

[Here is a JSFiddle for the code](https://jsfiddle.net/Uxrieg/jnwrc5ay/300/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 2;
  $('#btnAdd').on('click', function() {
    $('#company').append('<li><hr> Company N°' + counter + ' <input id="siteAdd" type="button" value="Add Site" /><input id="siteRemove" type="button" value="X"/></li>');
    counter++;
  });
  $("#btnRemove").on('click', function() {
    if (counter == 2) {
      alert("You need to have at least one company !");
      return false;
    }
    $('li:last').remove();
    counter--;
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 1;
  $('#company').on('click', '#siteAdd', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').append('<p>Site N°' + counter + ' <input id="prmAdd" type="button" value="Add PRM" /><input id="prmRemove" type="button" value="X" /></p>');
    counter++;
  });
  $('#company').on('click', '#siteRemove', function() {
    if (counter == 1) {
      alert("You need to have at least one site !");
      return false;
    }
    $('p:last').remove();
    counter--;
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 1;
  $(document).on('click', '#prmAdd', function() {
    $(this).closest('li p').append('<span style="margin-left: 10px;">PRM N°' + counter + '</span>');
    counter++;
  });
  $(document).on('click', '#prmRemove', function() {
    if (counter == 1) {
      alert("You need to have at least one PRM !");
      return false;
    }
    $('span:last').remove();
    counter--;
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="company">
  <li> Company N°1
<input id="siteAdd" type="button" value="Add Site" />
<input id="siteRemove" type="button" value="X" />
  </li>
</div>
<br>
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="+ Company" />
<input id="btnRemove" type="button" value="- Company" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: __Identifiers in HTML must be unique__, Use common classes here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/mj3nh7ap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always getting the last P on the page and removing it, change the following code

```
$('p:last').remove();
```

to

```
$(this).closest('li').find('p:last').remove();
```

Comment: @KRIED Constantin accept and upvote the answer is this working for you

Comment: Sorry, just saw the other buttons had the same issue:

Updated https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/307/